# Is there a way to check if Many2one res.users record exists already

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

> I'm creating my own module to manage agents accounts in odoo. where i do need to verify if a res.user if already in agent, to avoid creating agent with the same res.user account

```py
class Agent(models.Model):
    _name = 'agent.a'

    agent_id = fields.Many2one(
        'res.users',
        string='Agent',
        default=lambda s: s.env.user)
    agent_image = fields.Binary(string='Photo')
    local_id = fields.One2many('local.n', 'Localisation_Af', string='Localisation')
```

```py
@api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        res = super(Agent, self).create(vals)
        modelObj = self.env['agent.a']

        for record in res:
          rec = modelObj.search([('agent_id', '=', record.agent_id.login)])
            if rec:
               raise ValidationError(('Already exists'))
            else:
                return res
```

> But the result is always True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below code for checking

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals.get('agent_id',False):
        modelObj = self.env['agent.a']
        rec = modelObj.search([('agent_id', '=', vals.get('agent_id',False))])
        if rec:
           raise ValidationError(('Already exists'))
    return super(Agent, self).create(vals)
```

Please be informed that we cannot loop res in create that is not a right method and in your code you are checking the conditions after creating the record so always the search result will be true.

Comment: Thankkk youu it worked , could you please explain why ('agent_id',False) there is false

Comment: It is checking because if no agent id comes in vals then inside if condition the value should be false other wise error will come as no agent id in vals. If we give false then it will take false if no agent id.

Comment: If no agent id comes it means it wasn’t created so it already exists, isn’t it ? I didn’t really get it

Comment: Actually if no agent_id means no agent_id created, for that case if you give vals.get('agent_id'), then error will come. In order to avoid error we give False as default. If no agent-id then it will consider False as the vals value and then code will not further move inside if condition.

Comment: you can replace vals.get('agent_id',False) to vals.get('agent_id') by default it fall back to None